# JAX-RS/Jersey + Tomcat ServletContext is null

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to get the servlet context of a Jersey resource deployed in Tomcat, but whenever I attempt this I get a null pointer exception. My code is as follows:

```
@Path("/resource")
public class MyResource {

@Context ServletContext context;

public MyResource(){

    System.out.println("Context: "+context.getRealPath("/"));

}

}
```

My web.xml is configured like this:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyResource</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mypackage</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyResource</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any clue what my issue could be? Using Tomcat 6.0.33 and Jersey 1.12.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The injection doesn't happen until you use a service method to access a resource.

```
@Path("/resource")
public class MyResource {

   @Context ServletContext context;

   public MyResource() {
       System.out.println(context); //null
   }

   @GET
   @Path("subresource")
   public Response getASubResource() {
       System.out.println(context); // not null
       return Response.ok("OK").build();
   }



}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried to use Tom's code (I copied and pasted it) but I get null twice, both from the constructor and from the method. I invoked the method from a JSP page running on the same server, doing simply `new MyResource().getASubResource()`

Comment: @Krige does it happen when you call the resource method using a REST client?

Comment: Thank you, that helped me too and wasn't easy to find!